# Android studio not recognize the <uses-permission > entry in the AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android-studio, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I created simple sms messaging app on android studio 1.5 ([watch my eclipse app code on github](https://github.com/Hcohen1/TEXTING.git)), based on eclipse project which **alredy works fine** ([watch my android studio app code on github](https://github.com/Hcohen1/WORKINKTEXTING.git))

When I run the android studio version , it's not recognize the permission , produce this error : `Sending SMS message: uid 10166 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS`

I attach the android studio project manifest and gradle.build :

manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.findmee.myapplication5">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

the gradle.build :

```
>apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>android {
>    compileSdkVersion 23
>    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
>
>    defaultConfig {
>        applicationId "com.findmee.myapplication5"
>        minSdkVersion 15
>        targetSdkVersion 23
>        versionCode 1
>        versionName "1.0"
>    }
>    buildTypes {
>        release {
>            minifyEnabled false
>            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>        }
>    }
>}
>

>dependencies {
>    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
>    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
>    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
>}
```

>

Sorry about the ugly format of the grade code 
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

I fount that , think it will be useful for other users who try do debug/deploy their apps on android 6.0 devices.
The matter is you have to manualy enaple every permission to every app in youre 'apps' section on the setting **on youre device**.

Good luck!